# how to apply different colour to Overlapping region of circles in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a requirement of making the Overlapping circles increases in intensity, and if the same Lat Lng is entered again and again, the intensity increases too, with change in color. I searched for gradient options to use while providing the circle properties. Is there anyway i could achieve this?

[Requirement image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjswK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you would want to use [Google Maps Heat Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer)

The Google Maps JavaScript API can either render heatmap data client-side via the Heatmap Layer, or server-side via a Fusion Table

To load libaray:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false">
</script>
```

To add a Heatmap Layer, you must first create a new HeatmapLayer object, and provide it with some geographic data in the form of an array or an MVCArray[] object. The data may be either a LatLng object or a WeightedLocation object. After instantiating the HeatmapLayer object, add it to the map by calling the setMap() method.